# Expected Expression iOS Xcode

Tags: iphone, macos, if-statement

I'm trying to make a simple Calculator App and I'm following instructions in this video ( https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Uzq41DRC0-Q )

However, when i got to about 9:14, I got an error saying "Expected Expression" and some mark before the else statement. I cannot post images now, so post me everything you know, please. I'm a newbie, so any help would be appreciated!

My code (ViewController.m) :

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

}

- (IBAction)ClearPressed:(id)sender {
}

- (IBAction)MinusPressed:(id)sender {
}

- (IBAction)PlusPressed:(id)sender {
}

- (IBAction)EqualsPressed:(id)sender {
}

- (IBAction)NumberPressed:(UIButton*)sender;{
    NSInteger tag = sender.tag;

    if (operatorPressed == FALSE) {
        if (firstEntry == NULL) {
            firstEntry = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%li", (long)tag];
            _OutputLabel.text = firstEntry;
        }

    }
        else {
            firstEntry = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%li",firstEntry ,(long)tag];
            _OutputLabel.text = firstEntry;
        }

    else {       //HERE MY PROBLEM IS
        if (secondEntry == NULL) {
        secondEntry = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%li", (long)tag];
            _OutputLabel.text = secondEntry;

        }
        else {
            if secondEntry = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%li",firstEntry ,(long)tag];
            _OutputLabel.text = secondEntry;

        }
    }
}





@end
```

Comment: Please copy your actual code and paste it into your question.  Looking at someone else's video isn't necessarily going to match what you have.

Comment: if you cannot post images, please, post text... code is text...

Comment: It is there, hope you can help me.

Comment: You have a second `else` branch for the first `if` statement within `NumberPressed`. This is invalid; each `if` can have at most one `else`.

Answer (score 2):

You have two else statements. That's a no no.

```
- (IBAction)NumberPressed:(UIButton*)sender;{
    NSInteger tag = sender.tag;

    if (operatorPressed == FALSE) {
        if (firstEntry == NULL) {
            firstEntry = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%li", (long)tag];
            _OutputLabel.text = firstEntry;
        }

    }
    else {      // 1
        firstEntry = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%li",firstEntry ,(long)tag];
        _OutputLabel.text = firstEntry;
    }

    else {      // 2
        if (secondEntry == NULL) {
            secondEntry = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%li", (long)tag];
            _OutputLabel.text = secondEntry;

        }
        else {
            if secondEntry = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%li",firstEntry ,(long)tag];
            _OutputLabel.text = secondEntry;

        }
    }
}
```

Check where I marked off with 1 and 2. The first `else` should be `else if (someCondition)`. You can't have two else statements.

Comment: Even if i change the first "else" to "if else" it has another message, it says "expected '(' after if." Any new ideas?

Comment: @Sonicpeta What is it you're trying to do? `else if` needs a condition, so you would write it like `else if (someBoolean)` where `someBoolean` is a logical statement, like the one that you have in your first `if`. See my edit at the bottom, I meant `else if`, not `if else`. Sorry for the added confusion